# How to get the previous indexPath of an item in TableView Search / Filtering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

The title might seem a bit vague or confusing because I don't know how to explain my issue in one line.

I have a `tableview` with ~ 500 cells where the details are filled with an `API`. The `tableview` has `search / filter function` based on the name.

For example , "ABCD" is on cell 456 and if I search ABCD, the tableview will refresh and put ABCD on cell 0.

```
let searchtextupper = searchText.uppercased()
searchActive = true
filterdata = self.name.filter { $0.contains("\(searchtextupper)") 
Table.reloadData()
}
```

All this part is correct, but I want to get the indexPath of ABCD before the `tableview` is reloaded. I want to know that "ABCD" was on cell 456 before the `tableview` reloads and puts "ABCD" cell on cell 0.

How do I get that `indexPath`?

***Answer,incase someone else needs it :***

By using **@Abhisheks** answer.

I declared a simple int array on the class 
`var arrayofindices = [Int]()`

then added it in the search/filter function

```
let indexArray = name.indices.filter { name[$0].localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchtextupper) }
arrayofindices = indexArray
```

and on didSelectRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

var newindex = arrayofindices[indexPath.row]

searchmember.email = self.email[newindex]

}
```

Here `searchmember` is a `struct` and `email` is a `variable` in it. The `self.email` is a locally declared `array` to store email IDs which are received from API,having the entire list of emails before the filtering.

Comment: `name.firstIndex{ $0.contains(searchtextupper) }` or better `name.firstIndex{ $0.range(of: searchtext. options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }`. And don't *String Interpolate* strings.

Comment: @vadian Im not trying to get just the first index. I want my tableview to list all names with ABCD in it (like ABCD AC, ABCD JG, ABCD ZXZ etc)

Comment: What is the goal to get the indices in the full array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get index of filter position using this code. But first i think your name array might contain same name so in that case you need all the index for that name right? 
For that use this code -

```
let indexArray = name.indices.filter { name[$0].localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchtextupper) }
```

Here in indexArray you will get all the index for such name.

And if you sure your name array will not contain duplicate names then -

```
let index = name.firstIndex{$0 === searchtextupper}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding

Comment: Then you can use the first option, You will get entire index in the indexArray.